# The significant role of dual frames in the progress of Frame theory

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, linear-algebra, signal-analysis, wavelets

For a given frame  $\{\zeta_i\}_{i=1}^\infty$, any Bessel sequence  $\{\eta_i\}_{i=1}^\infty$ satisfying in the following identity   for every $\xi\in H$
$$\xi=\sum_{i=1}^\infty \langle \xi, \eta_i\rangle \zeta_i$$
is called a dual frame  associated with $\{\zeta_i\}_{i=1}^\infty$.

Q. What are the significant roles of the notion of dual frames in the progress of Frame theory. For example can we say that, if a frame is considered as a coded signal, any associated dual frame is used  to  decode it?!

Any other suggestion concerning its essential role?